# How to Convert LocalDate to Long in Kotlin / Java

Tags: java, kotlin, material-design

I need to set the Date in the material date picker. It requires `Long` to set the date.  I tried to do it with:

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DAY_FORMAT_PATTERN)
val selectedDate = LocalDate.parse(viewModel.selectedDateStateFlow.value, formatter)
val selectedDateToLong = selectedDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()

val datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
    .setTheme(R.style.DatePicker)
    .setSelection(selectedDateToLong)
    .build()
```

in this case date picker sets the date one day less.
Is there a more accurate conversion option?

for example:

```
I/System.out: viewModel.selectedDateStateFlow.value = 30 Nov, 2021 
I/System.out: selectedDate = 2021-11-30 
I/System.out: selectedDateToLong = 1638219600000
I/System.out: MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds() = 1638230400000
```

but date picker set "Nov 29, 2021"

the timezone on phone GMT+03:00 Moscow Standard Time

**UPD**
Compared the value of my conversion of the `LocalDate` into `Long` and `MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds()`. Received different values. What is the mistake of my translation?

Comment: I don't know too much about the Android APIs, but I would have expected this to work... Can you tell me what your system timezone is? Is it UTC+X?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example? I'd assume there's a timezone difference somewhere between parsing `viewModel.selectedDateStateFlow.value` and reformatting the data in the data picker. It would be good if the example included the values of `viewModel.selectedDateStateFlow.value`, `selectedDate`, `selectedDateToLong` and what the date picker shows.

Comment: Could it be that `viewModel.selectedDateStateFlow.value` is already "one day less" than what you expect? Did you check its value?

Comment: when i print value of `selectedDate` - i get correct date. By Default it current date. timezone on phone GMT+03:00 Moscow Standard Time

Comment: Try printing `MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds()`. Is that the same value as `selectedDateToLong`? If not, what is the numerical difference? Also, might as well try `ZoneOffset.UTC` instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()` :-)

Comment: when i select another date - i should get it in next time when i open date picker. Values for exapmle: `viewModel.selectedDateStateFlow.value = 30 Nov, 2021`, `selectedDate = 2021-11-30`, `selectedDateToLong = 1638219600000`. On date picker i get 29 nov 2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD2.**

The kind people in the comments were right about a possible error due to using a different time zone. On the advice of one of them, I tried:

```
val selectedDateToLong = selectedDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)...
```

instead of

```
val selectedDateToLong = selectedDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())...
```

It helped me